# Group actions of $G^2$

Tags: representation-theory

If a non-Abelian group $G$ acts non-trivially on a vector space $V$ that is itself non-trivial, i.e $V\neq \{0\}$, can we conclude that for a group action, there exists $g, h\in G$ and a vector $v\in V$ such that $g(hv)\neq h(gv)$?

Which I think directly follows from the non-Abelianity of $G$, but I couldn't manage to demonstrate things or come up with a counter-example (if there's any)

Comment: First, $[g,h] = ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, not $gh-hg$ (you seem to be conflating the ring-theoretic commutator with the group theoretic one). Second, no. If $G^{\rm ab}$ is nontrivial, you can take a nontrivial action of $G^{\rm ab}$ and lift it to $G$. For example, let $S_3$ act on $\mathbb{R}$ by letting the three cycles act like the identity, and the transpositions act like multiplication by $-1$.

Comment: The *ring* commutator being nonzero also means that $gh$ and $hg$ send some columns of the identity matrix to nonequal vectors.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question.

Comment: "for any group actions $(g,h)$"... doesn't seem to be what you mean. What you seem to mean is that for any group action there exist $g$ and $h$ and a vector $v$ such that $g(hv)\neq h(gv)$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's exactly what I had meant, to be honest.

Comment: I'll quickly edit my question before it's too late.

Comment: @Cake: there is no time limit on editing questions.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes. But if someone comes up with an answer, and if I edit the question so that the answer no longer addresses the question, it would be strange.

Comment: @Cake: that is indeed not a good idea, but here your edit was just clarifying the wording of the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks. Fortunately, under your assistance (and with Mr. Magidin), I managed to improve the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nontrivial action" is not sufficient. If $G^{\rm ab}$ is nontrivial, you can just take a nontrivial action of $\rho\colon G^{\rm ab}\to \mathsf{GL}(V)$ and define a nontrivial action $\sigma\colon G\to\mathsf{GL}(V)$ byy $\sigma=\rho\circ\pi$, where $\pi\colon G\to G^{\rm ab}$ is the canonical projection. Then for any vector $v\in V$ we have
$$ \sigma(gh)(v) = \rho(\pi(gh))(v) = \rho(\pi(hg))(v) = = \sigma(hg)(v),$$
since $\pi(gh)=\pi(g)\pi(h) = \pi(h)\pi(g) = \pi(hg)$.

If the action is *faithful*, so that $gv=v$ for all $v$ if and only if $g=e$, then the answer is **yes**; because then if $g$ and $h$ do not commute than $[g,h]=g^{-1}h^{-1}gh\neq e$. If $g(hv) = h(gv)$, then $h^{-1}gh(v) = g(v)$, so $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh(v) = v$; that is, $[g,h]v = v$. Since we know that there must exist a $v$ for which $[g,h]v\neq v$, then for that $v$ we have $g(hv)\neq h(gv)$, as desired.

The answer is also **yes** if $G^{\rm ab}$ is trivial. For if $\rho\colon G\to\mathsf{GL}(V)$ is a nontrivial representation, then $\rho(G)$ is nontrivial, hence is nonabelian. Thus, there exist $g,h\in G$ such that $\rho(g)$ and $\rho(h)$ do not commute, which means that there must exist a vector $v\in V$ for which $\rho(gh)(v) \neq \rho(hg)(v)$. This gives $g(hv)\neq h(gv)$.